# Logout button is not responsive

Tags: css

I am trying to put the logout button at the left toolbar , i have done it by position but it is not reponsive nd by smalling the chrome this button disappers , i have tried margin also but of no use!! How can I do it ??

My HTML

```
<div class="user-button-container at-xl-12 "#userButton>
    <button  class="user-button "  md-button [mdMenuTriggerFor]="menu">
     <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start center">
<at-icon class="at-display-block"backgroundColor="purple" backgroundType="border"size="40px" fontSize="30px"></at-icon>
            <span class="name" fxHide="true" fxHide.gt-sm="false"></span>
            <md-icon></md-icon>
        </div>
    </button>
</div>
```

My CSS

```
 .user-button-container {
height: 100%;
font-weight: 400;

.user-button {
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 0;
position: relative;
left: 1050px;

  md-icon {
    font-size: 16px;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
  }

  .name {
    margin: 0 8px 0 10px;
  }
} }
```

Comment: That is not valid CSS.

Comment: plz mark my mistakes , in improving to do best css writing

Comment: You can't nest selectors like that. You can in SCSS or LESS, but not in CSS. So basically there must be a closing `}` before `.user_button`, and that selector itself might need to be scoped more closely, and also needs to be closed. Lastly, `md-icon` indicates that you're looking for an `<md-icon>` element, which I guess is wrong. In general, make sure to align your code using indentation. That makes it easier for yourself, but will also communicate your intent to others so they can help you spot errors.

Comment: Looking at it, this HTML looks freaky too. Maybe this will work for specific libraries, but I see element names and attribute declarations that I've never seen before.

Comment: Sorry my bad.. the css is written in scss.. i forget to mention it :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

also, it appears you are not closing your css items - make sure you are using {}

Comment: why am I getting downrated if the answer is marked correct and in line with the comment above??

Answer (score 0):

looks like you have the design specified for xl-format, but not for smaller formats. as far as I know you should always start from small (xs) to large (lg) and not the other way around. so maybe just changing the following could help:

```
div class="user-button-container at-xs-12 "#userButton>
```

instead of

```
div class="user-button-container at-xl-12 "#userButton>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using bootstrap use following class for desktop or mobile

```
  <div class="user-button-container col-md-12 col-xs-12"> 

  </div>
```